# How to pass multiple records to update with one sql statement in Dapper

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I am attempting to use one single Update statement to update multiple records with different values (I'm not trying to update many rows to have the same values which is pretty straight forward).  Here's what I'm trying right now:

```
    using (var cn = GetOpenConnection()) {

        // get items where we need to set calculated fields that will now be persisted in the DB
        var items = cn.Query<MaintenanceItem>("select TOP 500 * from [Maintenance] where Tolerance IS NOT NULL");

        foreach (var mi in maintItems)
        {
            // Set calculated fields on multiple recrods
            logic.CalculateToleranceFields(mi, true);
        }


        var updateInput = items.Select(a => new {a.ToleranceMonths, a.ToleranceDays, a.ToleranceHours, a.ToleranceLandings, a.ToleranceCycles, a.ToleranceRIN }).ToList();

       // THIS DOESN'T WORK - attempting to update multiple rows with different values
       var numResults = cn.Execute(@"UPDATE rm 
                SET rm.ToleranceMonths=ur.ToleranceMonths, 
                rm.ToleranceDays=ur.ToleranceDays, 
                rm.ToleranceHours=ur.ToleranceHours, 
                rm.ToleranceLandings=ur.ToleranceLandings, 
                rm.ToleranceCycles=ur.ToleranceCycles, 
                rm.ToleranceRIN=ur.ToleranceRIN 
            from [RoutineItems] rm
            Inner Join @UpdatedRecords ur ON rm.AircraftId=ur.AircraftId AND rm.ItemNumber=ur.ItemNumber", updateInput);

        Assert.IsTrue(numResults == maintItems.Count());

    }
```

Is this sort of bulk update possible with Dapper?  I would rather do the update in bulk rather than using a for loop to push the data into the DB.

Comment: you can create a User Type in Sql Server or you can emulate the bulk insert functionality by using XML and creating temp tables etc.. do a google search there are plenty of examples out there on line ..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like this isn't currently possible with one statement in Dapper.  That's totally understandable when considering what would need done under the covers to accomplish this.

What I ended up doing was using 3 statements to create a temp table, populate it the data that needs updated, and then call an update with a inner join to my temp table:

```
cn.Execute(@"create table #routineUpdatedRecords
                        (
                            AircraftId int, 
                            ItemNumber int,
                            ToleranceMonths int,
                            ToleranceDays int,
                            ToleranceLandings int,
                            ToleranceCycles decimal(12,2),
                            ToleranceRIN decimal(12,2),
                            ToleranceHours decimal(12,2)
                        );");


cn.Execute(@"Insert INTO #routineUpdatedRecords 
    VALUES(@AircraftId, @ItemNumber, @ToleranceMonths, @ToleranceDays, 
@ToleranceLandings, @ToleranceCycles, @ToleranceRIN, @ToleranceHours)", updateInput);

var numResults = cn.Execute(@"UPDATE rm 
                                SET rm.ToleranceMonths=ur.ToleranceMonths, 
                                rm.ToleranceDays=ur.ToleranceDays, 
                                rm.ToleranceHours=ur.ToleranceHours, 
                                rm.ToleranceLandings=ur.ToleranceLandings, 
                                rm.ToleranceCycles=ur.ToleranceCycles, 
                                rm.ToleranceRIN=ur.ToleranceRIN 
                            from [RoutineItems] rm
                            Inner Join #routineUpdatedRecords ur ON rm.AircraftId=ur.AircraftId AND rm.ItemNumber=ur.ItemNumber");
```

I believe this was faster than calling update in a loop since I was updating about 600K rows.

Comment: Hi Kento, do we need to delete #routineUpdatedRecords after all?

Comment: @ThienLong I don't think that deleting the temp table is necessary as it is scored to the session/connection in which it was created.  When your dapper query is finished, this session is closed as the temp table is removed by sql server.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/02337dd5-5cfd-40d8-b529-12dc557d6a7e/scope-of-table-variable-and-temp-table?forum=sqltools

Answer (score 1):

I know the thread is a little bit old. But instead of using temp table you can do like this. Gives a little bit nicer syntax.

```
string sql = @"UPDATE rm 
    SET rm.ToleranceMonths=@ToleranceMonths, 
    rm.ToleranceDays=@ToleranceDays, 
    rm.ToleranceHours=@ToleranceHours, 
    rm.ToleranceLandings=@ToleranceLandings, 
    rm.ToleranceCycles=@ToleranceCycles, 
    rm.ToleranceRIN=@ToleranceRIN 
    FROM [RoutineItems] rm
    WHERE rm.AircraftId=@AircraftId AND rm.ItemNumber=@ItemNumber
    ";

var numResults = cn.Execute(sql, updateInput);
```

Comment: This looks better cosmetically but just keep in mind the update statements will still be executed one at a time internally. So if you're looking to do an actual bulk update such that the target table isn't locked for an extended period of time the temp table approach is the only way AFAIK.